# Multilayer Perceptron backpropagation

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to figure out a question that asks why training times in MLP nets increase dramatically if unnecessary additional layers are added between the inputs and outputs. (It's not a HW question)

I guess it's something to do with the backpropagation process. I know that the weight updates only apply to neurons that have contributed to the error.. is it simply that there are more neurons and so there are more weight updates which takes a longer time? I don't see why that would cause a 'dramatic' increase though. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Weight updates don't apply to neurons, they apply to the connections between them. If you have two fully connected layers of *m* and *n* units, respectively, then you have *m* × *n* connections/weights/updates to perform.

Comment: In addition, it is not entirely true that "the weight updates only apply to neurons that have contributed to the error". Actually the weight update is applied proportionally to how much a connection has contributed to the error. So yes in theory if a connection has not contributed much to the error, it should not be updated much either. But in order to do this, you still have to compute all of them to know how much to update each weight. This means that regardless of how much a connection (or weight) has influenced the error value, it will still be updated, albeit for a negligible amount.